# get Home Location from a contact in Contacts List Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, contacts

i use the following code for get all Contacts:

```
    public void getContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                    String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Contact_Details dt = new Contact_Details(name, number, UIDD);

                    dataArray.add(dt);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    cur.close();


}
```

now i want to get the home location from Contacts. what can i do now. home location is shown in the following image.
[image]

Comment: check my answer please if ok mark the answer @Ibad Ur Rahman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code to retrieve address from contact

```
 Cursor pCur2 = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur2.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String address = pCur2.getString(pCur2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                        Log.d("tag", "Address: "+address);
                    }
                    pCur2.close();
```

this retrieve both phone and address

```
 public void getContacts() {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext())
            {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext())
                    {
    String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Log.d("tag", "PhoneNumber: "+number);

                    }
                    pCur.close();

                    //get address of the phone
                    Cursor pCur2 = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur2.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String address = pCur2.getString(pCur2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                        Log.d("tag", "Address: "+address);
                    }
                    pCur2.close();
                }
            }
        }
        cur.close();
    }
```

Comment: one more help required. can we take address and phone at one query. in above Cursor query how can i match these adresses to thier numbers.

Comment: its not together. how i can match that this phone number have this address.

Comment: the code above will display phone with its address no need for verify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167011/discussion-between-al-tegani-and-ibad-ur-rahman).